# Shopify - How to programmatically add a product to a cart with a custom app extension?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to make a custom app for my standard shopify hosted store.  The app ui appears on product pages.  It allows for certain add-on products to be added to the cart if the user clicks the button on the ui.  Now I have made an initial version of the extension easily enough that shows up on the product page.  However, how do I add an item to the cart?  Is it done with the Admin API?  Would I be using GraphQL?  I have read the Storefront API is not suitable because that is for making custom storefronts not hosted by Shopify.  I have read some things saying that the cart is stored in cookies on the user's web browser and not on the shopify servers until checkout.  Is that true?

I have already searched on the shopify community site and there is the same question being asked but zero replies.

Comment: you simply using AJAX API from Shopify to do cart actions from frontend.

Comment: So if you click on the add to cart button on the product page it also adds an associated product along with the product from the product form? 
This can be done in the theme. 
Find in your theme how the product page posts the product variant to the cart identify the associated product variant and post in the same way, either in the same process by adding the associated product variant to the array being posted to cart.js or by chaining another process that adds a second product after the first product is added using the same process.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I add an item to the cart?

Check out the [Shopify AJAX API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax). The [cart reference documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/ajax/reference/cart) details how to query for what items are already in the cart and how to add items.

> Admin API? Would I be using GraphQL?

No. The endpoints under these APIs require authentication so definitely don't use them client side from the storefront.